# How to insert row after fetching data using IMPORTRANGE

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have 2 sheets, Sheet1 and Sheet2.
Sheet1 uses `IMPORTHTML` to import 2 tables from a website

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp","table",1)
=IMPORTHTML("https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp","table",3)
```

Also, I have set up a trigger to fetch this data every minute from the website. this works absolutely fine.
Sheet2 uses ImportRange function to import data from sheet1.

```
=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bLfZv3L9NtWzeIPfT0ZNM0Osju7T5AR91ybR4e-dBbU/edit#gid=0","trades!A1:V112")
```

Now I need Sheet2 to import data from Sheet1 every minute and paste it one below the other so that I can process the data.
I am new to google scripts and have managed to get the code in sheet2 that looks like this:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var cellFunction='=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bLfZv3L9NtWzeIPfT0ZNM0Osju7T5AR91ybR4e-dBbU/edit#gid=0","trades!A1:V112")';
sheet.getRange('A1').setValue(cellFunction);
// This logs the value in the very last cell of this sheet
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
var lastCell = sheet.getRange(lastRow, lastColumn);
//Logger.log(lastCell.getValue());
  sheet.insertRowsAfter(lastRow, 1);

}
```

I am trying to fetch the last cell and then insert 1 row after the last cell so that the next data will be fetched below the first range.
I have set up a time-driven trigger for Sheet2, to fetch data every minute, but it does not seem to work.

Can someone tell me where is it that I am going wrong? The result is the same data in the same cells. The data is not being fetched one after another

Comment: you could do this with formula too if you are interested

Comment: Formula evaluation is not instantaneous. Read about flush